# In Imagemagick for linux how do I do a batch convert for a directory

Tags: php, linux, bash, command, imagemagick

I want to be able to specify the location in both where to scan and where the converted file will go.

It's just there is a lot of conversions and I've got a script which should sort it for me.
Currently I've tried

```
convert -resize 300x300 >  /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/normal/*.jpg /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/tn_med/$1.jpg
```

and

```
for i in $( ls /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/normal); do  /usr/convert resize 360x360 > /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/normal/$i  /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/tn_med/$i done;
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into the linux `find` command?  Specifically the `-exec` option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to repeat your long directory three times. Use a variable for the base. And don't use `ls`:

```
base="/media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29"
for file in "$base/normal/*"
do
    convert -resize 360x360 "$file" "$base/tn_med/$(basename $file)"
done
```

Instead of `basename` you could do it this way:

```
    convert -resize 360x360 "$file" "$base/tn_med/${file##*/}"
```

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help. I hope they work through php exec command - but they should..
Thank for the comment about odd chars - there shouldn't be but that's always the case.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in $( ls /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/normal); do
    convert -resize 360x360 /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/normal/$i  /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/tn_med/$i;
done
```

got it!

Comment: This won't handle filenames containing spaces.

Answer (score 1):

As comments suggested, you can use the `find` command:

```
outdir=/media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/tn_med
cd /media/usbdisk1/development/ephoto/richard/images/gallery/2007/29/normal
find . -iname '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -I{} -0 -r convert -resize 300x300 {} $outdir/{}
```

By using `-print0` and xarg's `-0` option, this also handles filenames with spaces and other odd characters.